# What is a PatternSyntax in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, microsoft.codeanalysis

This seems a fairly stupid question and I'm not sure it is suitable for StackOverflow.

A user of my tool has reported an error with the message

```
Unable to cast object of type
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.LiteralExpressionSyntax' to type
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.PatternSyntax'.
```

I don't know exactly what his code looks like (at least not yet). I might be able to reproduce the error if I could write some code containing a PatternSyntax.

My problem is, that I haven't a clue what language construct in C# generates a syntax node of type PatternSyntax.

Can anybody help me with an example?

Comment: In what source code is this happening?

Comment: I hope the user will send me some of his code tomorrow. I think it is some kind of switch statement. The actual error is in my visual studio extension, which I think is trying to replace the PatternSyntax with a string literal. I have been trying to make an example to reproduce the problem, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's part of the syntax generated from [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). The [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns) for this feature describes the grammar along with some more examples.

`PatternSyntax` is defined here: http://sourceroslyn.io/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Generated/Syntax.xml.Internal.Generated.cs.html#b554fa43e6090c28

The following inherit from `PatternSyntax`

```
DiscardPatternSyntax
DeclarationPatternSyntax
VarPatternSyntax
RecursivePatternSyntax
ConstantPatternSyntax
```

I believe one example of `VarPatternSyntax` is `var o` in the following:

```
static object CreateShape(string shapeDescription)
{
    switch (shapeDescription)
    {
        case var o when (o?.Trim().Length ?? 0) == 0:
            // white space
            return null;
        default:
            return "invalid shape description";
    }            
}
```

We can take the above code and feed it into [RoslynQuoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) to see how to generate it and it would look something like:

```
CasePatternSwitchLabel(
            VarPattern(
                SingleVariableDesignation(
                    Identifier("o"))),
            Token(SyntaxKind.ColonToken))
        .WithWhenClause(
            WhenClause(
                BinaryExpression(
                    SyntaxKind.EqualsExpression,
                    ParenthesizedExpression(
                        BinaryExpression(
                            SyntaxKind.CoalesceExpression,
                            ConditionalAccessExpression(
                                IdentifierName("o"),
                                MemberAccessExpression(
                                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                                    InvocationExpression(
                                        MemberBindingExpression(
                                            IdentifierName("Trim"))),
                                    IdentifierName("Length"))),
                            LiteralExpression(
                                SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,
                                Literal(0)))),
                    LiteralExpression(
                        SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,
                        Literal(0)))))))
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, that make sense. I hadn't been looking for the five derived classes. Your example contains a **VarPatternSyntax**. Using an example from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause) I also have an example containing a **DeclarationPatternSyntax**. I wasn't aware of these language features. And by the way, thanks for your web pages on Roslyn, which I have referred to often.